# Implementing heartbeat mechanism in xmpp android

Tags: android, tcp, xmpp, smack

I am using a presistent xmpp connection in android device in a chat app.
To keep the connection open I want to use the TCP HEARTBEAT mechanism. I just want to know When the heartbeat step completes:

```
1. when a packet is sent on server and a response comes from server (Two steps) 
2. Or just packet sending is done from client side (1 step)
```

How to do it with smack library.Is using KeepAliveManager class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use XMPP Pings to the server as heartbeats. (a)Smack does that automatically. You can tune the settings in PingManager.